# How to access for editing an ALREADY OPENED DOCX (using win32com.client in python)

Tags: python

I would like to make some "magic" in previously opened MS Docx (like a VS script), but I do not find how I can do it.
I have seen examples only like "word.Documents.Open" after Dispatch.

**I can do it with excel (I can access the opened MS Excel file on "the fly") for example:**

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
xl = Dispatch("Excel.application")
xl.Visible = True
xl.Sheets["Action"].Select
current=xl.Sheets["Action"]
...
```

**How I can do it in MS Word as well?**

I hope I was understandable.
Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I got it.
The key is: "word.ActiveDocument"

Here is the code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch

word = Dispatch('Word.Application')
word.Visible = 1
doc=word.ActiveDocument

for word_t in doc.Words:
     print(word_t)
```